# Any framework to simplify webSQL coding?

Tags: sql, jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, jqtouch, web-sql

I'm using various HTML5/JS frameworks like jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch and jQTouch. Is there some kind of framework that could make it simpler to use the webSQL stuff?

I'm planning to deploy to WebKit-based platforms so it should work the same everywhere. I'm just looking for something that will give me a kick start.

Answer (score 1):

There is really none. Thanks to W3C for dropping WebSQL before anyone implemented indexedDB. I had to do my own SQL-proxyclasses for Sencha Touch, which I might share later on. The code is ugly, but works pretty good with associations and so on.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code so I can do the same? Looking to learn here as this is required for my little project and I can't use localstorage :) Thanks!

Comment: [Okay, here it is](https://github.com/tv/SQLStorageProxy). You will need to change it a bit, I'm sure. It's not yet made modular. You should be fine editing models and openDatabase-function. And yep, no comments :D. I'll add some example to read me. Good luck, have fun! I hope someone had time to play with this and correct it out..